# rdlc Report with multiple datatable c# with stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc, reportviewer

I have Stored Procedure which returns Dataset Consist of (4 Datatables) i want to bind each Table with some Tablix or Table or in other way in RDLC

4 Tables consists of

1. Basic Details
2. Opening Balance
3. Transactions
4. Closing Balance

i want to keep design as per following but report Designer is showing only first DataTable (Result Set)from Stored Procedure.
I want to Bind Other DataTables too.

[image: Required Report Design]

[image]

Comment: Return all the details you require in a single stored procedure's select.
I've done quite a bit of BI and as far as i know, you cant connect multiple datasets to a single table..Am i misunderstanding what you are asking ?

Comment: You need to share 1. the code segment that loads DataSet returned by StoredProcedure.
2. the code segment that pass on this DataSet to the report - this will enable me to help.

Comment: @BernardWalters...Rupesh for your valuable time i got solution. I am posting it